# Regarding private network IP filtering

Tags: java

I am trying to filter out private network IPfrom URLs.
Previously I had this code

```
 if(!sCurrentLine.startsWith("192.168") && !sCurrentLine.startsWith("172.") && !sCurrentLine.startsWith("10.")&& !sCurrentLine.startsWith("127.0.0"))
```

Data Example

```
10.1.1.83/nagiosxi/
10.1.1.83/nagiosxi//rr.php?uid=18-c96b5fb53f9
127.0.0.1/tkb/internet/
172.18.20.200/cgi-bin/topstats.pl?submit_type=topstats&time=00:2
```

Here is my new code

```
 Pattern privateIp=Pattern.compile("(^127\\.0\\.0\\.1)|(^10\\.)|(^172\\.1[6-9]\\.)|(^172\\.2[0-9]\\.)|(^172\\.3[0-1]\\.)|(^192\\.168\\.)");
 while((sCurrentLine=br.readLine())!=null)
{

            Matcher pnm=privateIp.matcher(sCurrentLine);

            if(!pnm.matches())
            {
              System.out.println("not match");

            }
}
```

I am thinking of using Pattern Match. However, `Pattern.compile` doesn't take this regular expression.

Or is there any function that can handle private network IP.

Any thought on that?

Comment: `Pattern.compile dosen't take this regular expression` could you show us your code and error massage/stack trace (if there is any)?

Comment: Why would you need regex for this?

Comment: Note that "^172." is not good enough for private IP's in the classB type, can be anything from 172.16.xxx.yyy through 172.31.xxx.yyy. i.e. 172.0.0.1 is *public*, not private (and belongs to 172-0-0-1.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a guess but is it possible that you are not escaping `\` in String representing pattern because

```
Pattern.compile("(^127\\.0\\.0\\.1)|(^10\\.)|(^172\\.1[6-9]\\.)|(^172\\.2[0-9]\\.)|(^172\\.3[0-1]\\.)|(^192\\.168\\.)");
```

compiles fine for me (although I didn't test it on any data yet).

### Update after your edit

I can see that you are using `matches` method to check if you regex is at start of line. This wont work because `matches` checks if regex matches entire data. Try changing this method to `find`

```
if (!pnm.find()) {
    System.out.println("not match");
}
```

Comment: @draford As I told that was just guess, because without your actual code I wont be able to help you more.

Comment: @draford Could you add examples of data are you using to test it? When I put `"127.0.0.1"` in `sCurrentLine` it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please check it out I think I should split a domain and do match

Comment: @draford `matches()` checks if entire data matches regex, and in your case after IP you have some data that is not matched by regex. Try changing your method to `find()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the InetAddress class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] addrs = {"127.0.0.1", "8.8.8.8", "172.1.2.3", "10.200.34.5", "192.168.111.1", "fc00::1", "www.google.com"};
    for (String a : addrs) {
        try {
            InetAddress ina = InetAddress.getByName(a);
            System.out.printf("Is %s private? %s\n", ina.toString(), ina.isSiteLocalAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

produces:

```
Is /127.0.0.1 private? false
Is /8.8.8.8 private? false
Is /172.1.2.3 private? false
Is /10.200.34.5 private? true
Is /192.168.0.1 private? true
Is /fc00:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 private? false
Is www.google.com/173.194.46.20 private? false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to find out if the IPAddress is Local or external. This checks for RFC 1918

```
String ipAddressAr[]    =   
            { "192.168.1.1" , 
              "172.18.20.200",
              "10.1.1.83",
              "127.0.0.1",
              "172.18.20.200"


            };


        String ipAddress    =   null;
        String ipAddressSplit[] =   null;
        int ipAddressIntSplit[] =   {0,0,0,0};

        for (int i = 0; i < ipAddressAr.length; i++) {
            ipAddress = ipAddressAr[i];
            ipAddressSplit = ipAddress.split("\\.");
            ipAddressIntSplit[0]    = Integer.parseInt ( ipAddressSplit[0] );
            ipAddressIntSplit[1]    = Integer.parseInt ( ipAddressSplit[1] );
            ipAddressIntSplit[2]    = Integer.parseInt ( ipAddressSplit[2] );
            ipAddressIntSplit[3]    = Integer.parseInt ( ipAddressSplit[3] );

            /*
             * RFC 1918
             * 
            The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
               following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

                 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
                 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
                 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
            */ 
            if ( 
                    ( ipAddressIntSplit[0] == 10 ) ||
                    ( ( ipAddressIntSplit[0] == 172 ) && ( ipAddressIntSplit[1] >= 16 && ipAddressIntSplit[1] <= 31 ) ) ||
                    ( ipAddressIntSplit[0] ==   192  && ipAddressIntSplit[1] == 168  ) ||
                    ( ipAddressIntSplit[0] ==   127  && ipAddressIntSplit[1] == 0 && ipAddressIntSplit[2] == 0  ) 
                    ){
                System.out.println( "IP Address: " + ipAddress + " is Local. ");
            }else{
                System.out.println( "IP Address: " + ipAddress + " is NOT Local. ");
            }
        }
```